# Python Dataframe string format

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a dataframe, using the results of the combinatorics.
The problem is that the formatting of the string is coming out funny.  I am hoping someone can guide me as to what I am doing wrong.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2 variables
  File "/home/jeremy/Desktop/jmpAnalysis/index.py", line 16, in <module>
"Food Exp", "HH Size"
    xData = data[[comb]]
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: '[\'"Food Exp", "HH Size"\'] not in index'
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import itertools

data = pd.read_csv("deaconFoodData.csv")

for i in range(2,10,1):
    xCombinations = itertools.combinations(["Food Exp", "HH Size", "HH Inc", "Highest Ed Head", "Age Head", "Shopping Time", "Kid <6", "Kid 6-18", "Eating Healthy"], i)
    print(str(i) + " variables")
    for combination in xCombinations:

        comb = str(combination)
        comb = comb.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("'","\"")
        print(comb)
        yData =  data['Shopping LH']
        xData = data[[comb]]
        #xData =  data[str(combination).replace("(","").replace(")","")]
        print(xData)
        #y = sm.add_constant()
```

UPDATE:
 LINK TO GITHUB AND CSV https://github.com/deacons2016/DeaconFood

Comment: I do not know what is in deaconFoodData.csv but you should read http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to answer without knowing what is in your input data. Without the input data or other things, inspection would lead to a guess that you want to do:

```
data[comb]
```

instead of:

```
data[[comb]]
```

Also, if that combination is not in your input data, indexing for it will fail. You either need to catch the KeyError or use `data.get(comb)` and check the return value to make sure it's valid.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I added the github link above with the csv

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I just converted the tuple to a list.  x = list(tuple)

Comment: Thanks @TreyHunner  - It makes me wait for a day before I can accept it.  Thanks for the info though!